Why is Kamakhya also known as Kamarupa?
People usually call Kamarup Kamakhya. Kamakhya is the name of the Goddess. So it makes sense to name that place as Kamakhya. But, why is the place also known as Kamarupa?

Kāmarūpa was the older name of the Kāmākhyāpīṭha.

@Bingming why? That is the question.

Are you aware of Lalitā being Kāmeśvarī and Kāmapūjitā ? About this is mentioned in Lalitopākhyāna. She is also known as Kāmākṣī.

Kāmākhyā = Kāma + ākhyā, where ākhyā means nāma, kīrti, or saundarya or appearance. Who is Kāmarūpa except Devī who made Śiva himself mohita over her ? The same Śiva who burnt Kāma himself in fury

@Bingming Reference?

Lalitopākhyāna, Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa, it was already mentioned above

@Bingming No. No. "Who is Kāmarūpa except Devī who made Śiva himself mohita over her ?" What is the reference to this? Looks like this is your conjecture.

Kāmadāyinī, Kāmadhuk, Kāmakalārūpā,  Kāmkelitaraṅgitā, Kāmakoṭikā, Kāmākṣī,  Kāmapūjitā, Kāmarūpiṇī, Kāmasevitā, Kāmeśvaraprāṇanāḍī, Kāmyā, etc. are names of Devī mentioned in Lalitā sahasranāma. If you think I am wrong that can be verified. And is Pārvati not the wife of Śiva, do you need śāstrīya pramāṇa for even that? If you do, that's available in several purāṇas, including Śiva Purāṇa, etc.?  Did Pārvati not have Skanda as her son with Śiva, that they both had saṁyoga, which is supported by Śiva Purāṇa, etc.?

Śiva burnt Kāma himself, but later Lalitā herself resurrected him, and blessed him so that Śiva would be mohita i.e. he would be struck by his arrows this time. As a result, Śiva had vivāha with Gaurī, and they both had Skanda as their son. This is mentioned in 30th adhyāya of Lalitopākhyāna.
If Lalitā is not kāmarūpa, who is? Kāma himself does pūjā of Lalitā.

@Bingming Your conjecture. Give direct reference where Lalita is referred to as kamarupa.

There are no conjectures here, only ignorance on your own part with regards to śāstras, even the names Kāmarūpiṇī, etc. are already mentioned in Lalitā sahasranāma, as I already said above. I have no interest in continuing on with this discussion, when you seem uninterested in reading properly and checking the sources referred to you. There's no point in pouring water in a vessel that's kept upside down, it wouldn't fall into it.

@Bingming You are making personal attacks because you do not have proper references. I can understand. Period.
